# yesinductane heating stainless steel bolts

Tags: coil

I wish to heat 303 stainless 10 mm bolt to form an eye with 10 mm ID.

My gas torch just doesn't get the bolt hot enough for me to hammer it into the shape I need. So I would like to make an inductance coil running from the mains 220 V. I guess 2 kW power would be more than enough to heat the stainless bolt. I think the internal diameter of a hollow coil could be say 20 to 25 mm. I don't know the wire size or the number of turns of insulated wire I would need to make the coil.

I also don't know where is the most economic place to buy the wire I need.
When in use I would cool the coil by air from my compressor and I think that would not cool the stainless to much to prevent heating to bright red?
Can you assist me in designing/specifying what I would need please?

Comment: I can’t answer you question, but I don’t this it is realistic to provide that much heating power with an inductance connected to mains. According to where you leave, means is either 50Hz or 60Hz. Induction heating uses much higher frequencies (several MHz) to be efficient.

Comment: A bigger torch or a forge come to mind...

Comment: I would heat up the bolt in a coal fire. Low tech. It works.

Comment: @John, what is "yesinductane heating" in your question title and why is it not capitalised?

Comment: Surely this is a job for your local blacksmith?

Comment: Better to buy it pre-made, especially as forming 10mm stock around a 10mm diameter will be quite challenging.

Comment: You could machine some bar stock instead: it might be easier. Isn't this a question for [engineering.stackexchange.com](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Answer (score 2):

For heating a thick steel bolt to red glow, you can't use a wire for the inductor coil. It has to be copper tubing, and you have to run plenty of cooling water through it. Otherwise the coil tube is going to melt through before your bolt is red.

Also, 50/60 Hz will get you nowhere. At least a few kHz are needed, and the inverter should be in the 10kW power range for that bolt you describe.

You can certainly build something like this yourself but it makes no sense to do that for one single bolt.

Answer (score 0):

You will have less success with inductance heating a stainless steel.
Like steel, stainless steels are relatively poor conductors of electricity, with significantly lower electrical conductivity than copper.
Ferritic and martensitic stainless steels are magnetic. Annealed austenitic stainless steels are non-magnetic. Work hardening can make austenitic stainless steels slightly magnetic. Think about it.